# Spring JPA java.util.Date to Mysql timestamp with wrong date value

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have a JPA entity with a date field is persisted into Mysql DateTime.

Field:

```
  @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
  private Date creationDate;
```

Column:
  `CREATION_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,

Setter:

```
request.setCreationDate(new Date());//Value set to current date
```

I am getting an strange error that persisted date is 8 hours lesser than the current time. Tried few approaches as below:

1. Using `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` for the field
2. Setting default TimeZone
   `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+8"));`
3. Printing the date before setting, which displays the correct value.
4. Setting the timezone at mysql layer as well:
   `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00'; 
   SET SESSION time_zone = '+8:00';`
5. Changing the field type to `java.sql.Timestamp`

none of the above approaches helped. Anyone had a similar issue? Any clue?

Comment: Have you deployed your code in a Cloud environment?

Comment: its deployed in rehl bare metal server.

Comment: I wonder what the JPA providers log says? You have looked at it haven't you? ...

Comment: Haven't  tried  printing the sql and parameter values. I will try enabling it. This issue is not happening in my dev machine which is running in oracle jdk happening only in the server which is running openjdk. Is there any difference between oracle and open jdk in this regard?

Comment: I tried printing the hibernate logs the time stamp is correct

Comment: if I set the date variable as a string it is stored properly. meanwhile found this thread which talks about mysql/connector timezone issue https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71084

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue, the problem was in jdbc connection URL.

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://:3307/dbname?**useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC**

due to the server time zone setting in the URL, GMT+8 time was converted to UTC which was leading to the 8 hours time difference. After removing the serverTimezone parameter in the URL, date is working fine. Thank you Neil and Shazin for your time and support.